# Can I create invalid values with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot, rspec3

I have email factory (spec/factories/email.rb):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :email, class: String do
    skip_create

    transient do
      username 'user'
      subdomain 'mail'
      domain_name 'example.com'

      host { [subdomain, domain_name].compact.join('.') }
    end

    trait(:with_blank_host) { host '' }
    trait(:with_blank_username) { username '' }

    initialize_with { new("#{username}@#{host}") }
  end
end
```

And I have spec (spec/models/user_spec.rb):

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  # ...

  it { is_expected.to_not allow_value(FactoryGirl.create(:email, :with_blank_host)).for(:email) }
  it { is_expected.to_not allow_value(FactoryGirl.create(:email, :with_blank_username)).for(:email) }
end
```

Is it correct to use FactoryGirl in this way? Is it a bad practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the logic behind creating those email without host/username won't be use anywhere else but the tests. Why do you want to keep it in the factory?

Why not simply doing:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :email, class: String do
    skip_create

    transient do
      username 'user'
      subdomain 'mail'
      domain_name 'example.com'

      host { [subdomain, domain_name].compact.join('.') }
    end
    initialize_with { new("#{username}@#{host}") }
  end
end

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  # ...

  it 'should not allow blank host' do
    is_expected.to_not allow_value(FactoryGirl.create(:email, host: '')).for(:email)
  end

  it 'should not allow blank username' do
    is_expected.to_not allow_value(FactoryGirl.create(:email, username: '').for(:email)
  end
end
```

On top of that does it really make sense to have a factory to create a email string? why not simply using a string (This is way simpler):

```
is_expected.to_not allow_value(FactoryGirl.create(:email, host: '')).for(:email)
```

vs

```
is_expected.to_not allow_value('test@').for(:email)
```

If you want to have a consistent :email through your test, why not putting it in the User.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user

    transient do
      username 'user'
      subdomain 'mail'
      domain_name 'example.com'

      host { [subdomain, domain_name].compact.join('.') }
    end

    before(:create) do |user, evaluator|
      user.email = "#{username}@#{host}"
    end
  end
end
```

But if the logic belongs to those particular tests, why abstracting all of this in factory instead of simply using a before/callback. **As a rule of thumb, I only put logic that will be used across spec files in the factory, everything else is in the proper before/after callback**

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  before :each do
    # logic before each test of the file
  end

  context 'email validation'

    before :each do
      # logic before each test concerning the email validation
      # useful to factor stuff that will be used multiple time
      # e.g.
      #  @email_ok = 'user@example.com'
    end

    it 'should not allow blank host' do
      # test specific setup
      # useful for stuff only used in this test
      # e.g
      #  email_no_host = 'user@'

      # expectation
    end
  end
end
```

In short:

**What you're doing would work of course. This is not bad practice per se. It just doesn't make much sense IMHO.**

**EDITED**

You could also add an helper inside the test scope in order to not make the model too fat:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  context 'email validation'
    def generate_email(**opts)
        options = {username: 'user', subdomain: 'mail', domain_name 'example.com'}.merge(opts)
        username = options[:username]
        host = options[:host] || "#{options[:subdomain]}.#{options[:domain_name]}"

        "#{username}@#{host}"
    end

    it 'should not allow blank host' do
      is_expected.to_not allow_value(generate_email host: '').for(:email)
    end

    # Here goes 100 other use of generate_email
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree with your answer. Your first source is very helpful for me. But what if I need to test 10+ different values? I think that my spec will look dirty and fat

Comment: The factory will be dirty and fat if you factor that code in it for a small subset of your tests. If you do use directly the string such as `is_expected.to_not allow_value('test@').for(:email)` this won't fatten your tests. moreover you could add a method helper inside your tests context for only the test in the context (I'll edit the answer)

Comment: Thanks again! I took your advice and I'll use invalid strings directly except complex values for which it makes sense to use helpers or factories(for multiple specs)